# looping a unnamed dictionary in python

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there a way to print both key and value of a anonymous dict in python.

```
for key in {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3}:
    print key, ":", #value
```

Comment: That is a `dictionary`, not a `list`

Comment: thanks everyone. I meant to say dictionary. accidentally typed it as list.

Comment: Why don't you use a list of tuples instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for key, value in {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3}.iteritems():
    print key, ":", value
```

By default, iterating over it returns its keys. .iteritems() returns 2-tuples of (key, value).

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
for  (key, value) in {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3}.items():
    print key, value
```

Answer (score 3):

To iterate over key/value pairs, you can use `.items()` or `.iteritems()`:

```
for k, v in {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3}.iteritems():
    print '%s:%s' % (k, v)
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just use:

```
for key,value in {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3}.items():
    print key, ":", value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [iteritems](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) method to iterate through the dict

```
for key, value in {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3}.iteritems():
    print key
    print value
```